# Передача данных в родительскую компоненту

Tags: reactjs

Пытаюсь разобраться с React.

По клике на заголовок 'Header' (в компоненте Data) вызываю функцию обработчик handler() у родителя (компонента App), и хочу поменять у родителя state. Функция отрабатывает, но state не находится. Как можно привязать state к вызову?

```js
class Data extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <h1 onClick={this.props.data_function}>{this.props.data_text}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {in: 'Header'}
    }

    handler(){
      console.log('this.state.in', this.state.in);
      //this.setState({in: 'New_Header'});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Data data_text={this.state.in} data_function={this.handler} />
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App />, 
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Привязать можно добавив в конструкторе:
this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

В конструкторе будет так:

```
 constructor(){
    super();
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.state = {in: 'Header'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `data_function={this.handler}` на `data_function={this.handler.bind(this)}` либо в конструкторе пропишите `this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)`